# Draw an area on google map and get a list of all cities covered by that area

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any such functionality provided by google maps API, such that I draw a random area on google map and then through some functions in the API, receive a list of all cities and sectors that were covered under that drawn area ?

Any information or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A City is normally divided into Sectors - I am talking about India, don't know about other countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that functionality does not exist (as far as I know, anyway).  You can try to fake it by selecting a sufficient number of points in your polygon and reverse geocode them, but obviously that is an imperfect solution in terms of both performance and completeness.

Barring that, there may be resources that you can license for a fee or there may be a resource made available by the government of India that may help you solve this problem.  (Or perhaps there is not.  I'm speculating.)

Comment: Can you give me a short example of how to select a number of points and reverse geocode the points ? I have no idea about Google Maps API. Before starting, I wanted to get informed in advance whether the task I am trying to attempt is possible or not.